# How do I use SecureString securely?

Tags: c#, .net, security

All of the examples I have seen end up converting a SecureString back to a standard string before using it, defeating the object. What's a good way of using a secure string without this problem?

I know I can marshall the SecureString to a BSTR but what can I do with this BSTR? Can I get the characters back one at a time? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

This link includes a lot of helpful information, including how to get an unmanaged memory block for passing the string to native code (that is presumably also secure), a BCL class that uses it, and links to a couple examples:

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/03/31/3851.aspx

The main thing is that it's not really used that much yet, but you are free to make your own libraries that rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring_members.aspx) describing the SecureString says it best:

> Represents text that should be kept confidential.

SecureStrings are not meant to be used like strings.  They are meant to be limited-access holders of information that should be subject to increased security.

If you want to modify the contents of a SecureString, all of the necessary methods are there.

<s>However, if you need to get the value of the secure string, you must ToString() as no other methods are exposed to do this.</s>

In other words, don't use SecureStrings like strings.

Comment: ToString does not return the contents of the string, only the object type name. You can marshall the SecureString to a bstr but I don't know how you can use it from that point on.

Just because it is confidential doesn't mean you don't need to work with it. A credit card number is confidential but I still want the money!